# Docs for React Native? Can I use normal React docs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to apologize in advance if this is a dumb question, but I've been Googling for a while and still can't find the answer :)

I'm looking for docs for React Native.  I've found stuff like [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator) or [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/components-and-apis), which seem to be docs for React Native specific stuff.  What I'm looking for is docs for the core React Native APIs, such as the setState method.

I have found [docs for setState for the React library](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate); React Native is clearly intended to  be very similar to React.

So my question is - w**here do I find docs for the core/basic React Native APIs** (like Component.setState) **and/or is it ok to use the docs for React when I can't find docs for RN** (because it's pretty easy to find docs for React)

Comment: Generally speaking, you are correct that RN is supposed to be very similar to React. Aside from the RN specific components that are provided by the api, the rest is supposed to function the same as react and it is safe to use those docs such as the component lifecycle. The links you shared are your best source of docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core principles you're talking about are all part of React. React Native doesn't add anything to this, it's only a UI layer on top of React. Therefore, the React docs are where you'll find the most info about what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

React Native is React framework + native mobile APIs working underlying, so all the react concepts live in RN when you develop an RN applications like state, props, component lifecycle in oppose to native android/iOS and you write JSX in RN instead of HTML (in reactjs) which gets transpiled to native widgets using an RN bridge working behind the scene in respective platform such as `<View/>` in RN will be transpiled to `android.view` in android or `UIView` in iOS.

So your application has native UI and with the bridge, RN exposes ways to directly access platforms native APIs such as `Camera` or `Bluetooth` or `SharedPreferences` or whatnot.

So. in order to learn RN, you can refer React docs for framework related concepts and the RN homepage's link which you quoted is the one also authentic which has docs for APIs specific to RN.

*Hope this helps. Cheers!*

Answer (score 1):

React Native is ReactJS for mobile, actually it has all the benefits of ReactJS, Facebook engineers managed to revolutionize the interfaces programming with the React technologies which generally follow the same principles.

let me give an example, React Native uses native elements to create native components and takes JavaScript for all shared features. on the other hand, ReactJS, uses virtual DOM to process changes faster.

So, first I recommend learn ReactJs principles and then start React native.